# Find the derivative of the integral

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can i find the derivative of the integral:

$$ f(x)=\left(\int_0^x g(s,x)\ ds\right)$$

I tried use FTC but im confused with the function $g(s,x)$,please help.

Comment: yes, sorry i edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [differentiation under integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) sign.

$$f'(x)  = g(x,x) - g(0,x) + \int_0^x \frac{\partial }{\partial x}g(s, x)ds$$